# How to plot this dataset?

Tags: plotting, physics

I have the following list of 3by3 dimension as an example (the listtot gives me the corresponding energy (ex:37.752812298486035`) for each angle set (ex:{0.`, 0.3141592653589793`,  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.2566370614359172`,
1.5707963267948966`}) of 6 electrons) and I want to plot the data to show clearly how the energy changes when the electrons' spins maintaining different angles with respect to each other (to do that I thought of using ListPlot3D, but if you have better ideas I appreciate that a lot):

```
  listtot = {{{37.752812298486035`, {0.`, 0.3141592653589793`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  6}}, {37.752812298486035`, {0.`, 0.3141592653589793`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  6}}, {37.752812298486035`, {0.`, 0.3141592653589793`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  6}}}, {{37.752812298486035`, {0.`, 0.3141592653589793`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  6}}, {37.11781609966486`, {0.`, 0.2630862667406051`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.2566370614359172`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  6}}, {34.125297721219795`, {0.`, 0.2630862667406051`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.4818657793200891`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  6}}}, {{33.522683744885754`, {0.`, 0.2630862667406051`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.5233731698273567`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  6}}, {33.522683744885754`, {0.`, 0.2630862667406051`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.9424777960769379`, 1.5233731698273565`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
  6}}, {33.39466567365792`, {0.`, 0.2630862667406051`, 
  0.6283185307179586`, 0.5455129752218801`, 1.5233731698273565`, 
  1.5707963267948966`}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}}};
```

I should rearrange my data as following to use it in ListPlot3D:

```
  Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@ listtot[[1]][[1]]
```

Now for every listtot[[i]][[j]] in which i and j are changing between 1&3, I need to store the data on a different list and plot all of them in one graph. I was thinking about writing the code to do the following procedure (which I need help with):

list1=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[1]][[1]]

list2=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[1]][[2]]

list3=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[1]][[3]]

list4=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[2]][[1]]

list5=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[2]][[2]]

list6=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[2]][[3]]

list7=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[3]][[1]]

list8=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[3]][[2]]

list9=Thread[{#3, #2, #1}] & @@listtot[[3]][[3]]

I need to write something like:

```
 ListPlot3D[{list1, list2, list3,...}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 AxesLabel -> {"electron index", "spin angle", "energy"}, 
 BaseStyle -> 12, ImageSize -> 400]
```

and I am asking for a way to write {list1, list2, list3,...,list9} or in other words to store the data in various lists: list1,... and plot them ;

again I appreciate any other method in case you have different ideas to show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lists1thru9 = Join @@ Map[Thread@*Reverse, listtot, {2}];

ListPlot3D[lists1thru9, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 AxesLabel -> {"electron index", "spin angle", "energy"}, 
 BaseStyle -> 12, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]